# Daily Rolling Count of Distinct Users on Different time periods

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to find the most optimal way to run the following query which I need to connect to tableau and visualise. The idea is to count 7 day active users, 30 day active users and 90 day active users for each day. So for today I want who was active and for yesterday and I want who was active within those timeframes.

To clarify users can be active multiple times within my time frames.
A count of 7 day actives users would be the distinct number of users who had a session with in the period todays date and todays date -6. I need to calculate this for every date within the last 6 month.

This is the query I have.

```
with dau as (
    select date_trunc('day', created_date) created_at,
    count(distinct customer_id) dau
    from sessions
    where created_date >= date_trunc('day', dateadd('month', -6, getdate()))
    group by date_trunc('day', created_date)
)
select created_at,
    dau,
    (select count(distinct customer_id)
    from sessions
    where date_trunc('day', created_date) between created_at - 6 and created_at) wau,
    (select count(distinct customer_id)
    from sessions
    where date_trunc('day', created_date) between created_at - 29 and created_at) as mau,
    (select count(distinct customer_id)
    from session_s
    where date_trunc('day', created_date) between created_at - 89 and created_at) as three_mau
from dau
```

It takes 30 min to run which seems crazy. Is there a better way to do it? I am also looking into the use of materialised views as a faster way to use this in a dashboard. Would this work?

The result I am looking to get would be a table where the rows are dates within the last 6 months and each column is the count of distinct users on 7, 30 and 90 periods from that date.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ideas are nice.  Of more help are sample data, desired results, and clear definitions of what you mean by "7 day active users" and so on.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some (very) ancient common parts they are substantially different.

Comment: It is redshift, my apologies!